# Is there a StyleCop+ version which works for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, stylecop, stylecop-plus

Is there a StyleCop+ version which works for Visual Studio 2017?
StyleCop+ offers more custom rules for making your style tougher.
Most of them have flexible settings, configured through user-friendly UI.
And a small example illustrates what this rule is about.

Comment: I use StyleCop Analyzers, it works with VS2017. However, UI won't be as nice as StyleCop+

Answer (score 0):

I'm using StyleCop Analyzers and, while I don't know how easy StyleCop+ is to use, the Analyzers are pretty straight-forward. There are some useful rules missing (that are in StyleCop+) but I'm using Menees Analyzers (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Menees.Analyzers.2017/) to help with some of those. Again, changing the settings and so on is probably not as easy as StyleCop+, but it's not too tricky.